# How to login to Facebook with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code to search facebook from a list of business names for associated facebook pages. It is working but currently popping up a page to login. How do I log in to facebook using the below code???

I know Selenium is time consuming but I dont have a very large list.

Thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver

def read_excel_file(file_name):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
    sheet = wb.active
    leads = [cell.value for row in sheet.iter_rows() for cell in row]
    return leads

def login_to_facebook(driver, email, password):
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
    time.sleep(5)
    email_input = driver.find_element("email")
    password_input = driver.find_element("pass")
    email_input.send_keys(email)
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    login_button = driver.find_element("login")
    login_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the login to complete, adjust this if needed

def scrape_contact_info(target_url, email, password):
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        login_to_facebook(driver, email, password)

        driver.get(target_url)
        time.sleep(5)
        resp = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')

        contact_info = {"address": None, "number": None, "email": None}

        contact_items = soup.select('div[data-pagelet="ProfileContactSection"] span[dir="ltr"]')

        for contact in contact_items:
            if '@' in contact.text:
                contact_info["email"] = contact.text.strip()
            elif len(contact.text.split("-")) > 2:
                contact_info["number"] = contact.text.strip()
            elif len(contact.text.split(",")) > 2:
                contact_info["address"] = contact.text.strip()

        return contact_info

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        driver.quit()
        return None

def save_to_excel(file_name, data):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    sheet.append(["Keyword", "Address", "Number", "Email"])

    for item in data:
        keyword = item["keyword"]
        address = item["address"]
        number = item["number"]
        email = item["email"]
        sheet.append([keyword, address, number, email])

    wb.save(file_name)

def main():
    try:
        file_name = "leadList.xlsx"  # Replace with your Excel file name
        email = "your_facebook_email_or_username"
        password = "your_facebook_password"
        keywords = read_excel_file(file_name)
        all_results = []

        for keyword in keywords:
            target_url = f"https://www.facebook.com/{keyword}"
            print(f"Searching for pages related to '{keyword}'...")
            contact_info = scrape_contact_info(target_url, email, password)
            if contact_info:
                contact_info["keyword"] = keyword
                print("Contact Information:")
                print(contact_info)
                print("-" * 50)
                all_results.append(contact_info)

        if all_results:
            save_to_excel("search_results.xlsx", all_results)
            print("Search results saved to 'search_results.xlsx'.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I dont know what to try

Answer (score 0):

You  might find [this article/tutorial](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/python-automate-facebook-login) helpful for your issue.

I think the main problem is

> ```py
>     email_input = driver.find_element("email")
>     password_input = driver.find_element("pass")
> ```

you should be using something like

```py
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    email_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pass")
```

See the section on [Navigating](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) a page in the documentation for more details and examples.